# How to remove Ubuntu 12.10 and install 10.04?

Tags: 12.10

I have a pc with windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10 dual boot. I want to remove Ubuntu 12.10 and I want to install Ubuntu 10.04LTS because my Micromax Wireless 3G modem is not supported in Ubuntu 12.10. Can you please tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest procedure would be to boot with the Live CD for 10.04LTS.

Install it on the current / partition by formatting it during installation. Select other partitions like home, swap etc. if applicable but do not format them.

When you reboot, Grub menu should indicate Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Comment: but the problem is when i am doing such thing, the grub is still showing Ubuntu 12.10 startup and I am unable to boot into the machine

Comment: Have you formatted the / partition? That is important and required